# Does neural networks learn distribution in training dataset?

Tags: neural-network, classification, training-data

I am trying to train a Convolutional Neural Network on dataset with imbalanced classes (20% class 1, 70% class 2, 10% class 3). I want the network to learn that class 1 and class 3 occur very rarely when compared to class 2.

Most of the stackoverflow answers suggest to balance the dataset by adding more data to under-represented classes or to prioritize weight updates.

**My questions**

1) Will the model learn by itself, the distribution of training dataset if I train without taking any measures to balance my dataset?

2) If they can learn the distribution of data what is the need to balance the dataset as suggested in many stackoverflow answers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the given case, you may be able to train a successful neural network for the imbalanced class. However, imagine you are trying to train a classifier, and you have 90% instances of class A, and 10% of class B.

A "solution" that is very easy to find, and is also very efficient is to create a network that always returns class A as the prediction, since this will have an accuracy of 90% (9/10 right predictions). Learning algorithms may have a very hard time moving away from this solution to a better one (it is possible that all possible small changes result in networks that perform worse than the original one!).

Having a more balanced training set means that such lazy solutions will result in lower performance (no more than 50% in the case of two well-balanced classes).

In short, balanced classes is a way to help the learning algorithm by discouraging bad solutions, even if theoretically training on imbalanced classes might sometimes work.

Comment: Is there a way to effectively train a regression model on a normally distributed dataset? . I want the network to learn that class 1 and lass 3 occur very rarely. IN this case balancing the training dataset doesnt make any sense.

Comment: If you are building a classifier then you want your network to be able to identify the correct class for a given example, so the network does not have to learn that any given class is very common or not, but rather it has to learn what makes an example belong to each class.

Comment: What I mean is: the relative frequency of your classes only affects how easily your learning algorithm works, not how the resulting network will behave.